# Angular display formatted number in input field

Tags: angularjs, binding, formatting

guys.
I have an input field:

```
<input type="number" name="price" ng-model="ctrl.form.price" required>
```

The problem is that whenever a user types digits it automatically formats it.
Example: 5 312 000.12313
However, when a user submits this form, the value of ctrl.form.price should be 5312000.12313. 
I know that there are filters, but as I know they can be used only for one way data binding. 
Any way to do this?

Comment: Shoulnd you be using an input type="text" then? And if you want to limit to only numbers, use a proper function for it ?

Comment: @GustavoGabriel, can you provide a basic example of this?

Answer (score 2):

You should write a directive with a parser and formatter. The parser function should convert from the displayed value with spaces to a number, and the formatter function converts the number to the displayed text.

Something like:

```
angular.module('app').directive('formattedNumber', formattedNumber);

function formattedNumber() {
   var directive = {
        restrict: 'A',
        require 'ngModel',
        link: link
   };
   return directive;

   function link(scope, element, attrs, ngModelController) {
       ngModelController.$parsers.push(parseNumber);
       ngModelController.$formatters.push(formatNumber);
   }

   function parseNumber(viewValue) {
       // convert text with spaces to number and return it.
   }
   function formatNumber(modelValue) {
       // convert numeric modelValue to formatted text and return it.
   }
}
```

Then just:

```
<input type="number" name="price" ng-model="ctrl.form.price"
  formatted-number required>
```

Comment: As I know $parsers are used to format data coming from user to server and formatters - from server to user. However, I need that as a user types text changes(the same as filter but for two way binding) which is something like from user to user

Comment: @RustamIbragimov, nothing to do with server, they are all about two way binding: `$parsers` convert the data from the displayed value in the view to the model value, `$formatters` convert from the model to the value displayed in the view (there was a typo in my example where I wrote `$parsers` instead of `$formatters` which I've now corrected)